# Integrating two expressions in Statistics

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I am reading the book Bayesian Statistics by Peter Lee, and came across this:

$$\int(x)(2\pi\phi)^\frac{-1}{2}\exp{\{\frac{-1}{2}(x-u)^2/\phi}\}dx = u + \int(x-u)(2\pi\phi)^\frac{-1}{2}\exp{\{\frac{-1}{2}(x-u)^2/\phi}\}dx$$
How did the author go from the first integral to the second? I am lost in the reasoning. Then he goes on to say, "the integrand in the last function is an odd function of $(x-u)$, and so vanishes [leaving only $u$]". Why is it an odd function and why does it vanish?

Comment: The integral of an odd function over an interval symmetric about zero is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, recall that if $$X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$$ is a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then the density of $X$ is $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}, \quad -\infty < x < \infty.$$  Since $f_X$ is a density, its integral over its support equals $1$:  $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) \, dx = 1.$$  From this, we conclude that $$ \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \mu f_X(x) \, dx = \mu,$$ since $\mu$ is a constant with respect to $x$.  It immediately follows that $$\begin{align*} \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x) \, dx &= \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty (\mu + x-\mu)f_X(x) \, dx \\ &= \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \mu f_X(x) \, dx  + \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu)f_X(x) \, dx \\ &= \mu + \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu) f_X(x) \, dx. \end{align*}$$  This completes the proof of the first claim.

Next, consider the integrand $$(x-\mu) f_X(x) =  (x-\mu) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}.$$  It is clear that this is a function of $x-\mu$; that is to say, $x$ and $\mu$ always appear together in the form $x-\mu$, so if we define the function $$g(x) = x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-x^2/(2\sigma)^2},$$ then the integrand is simply $g(x-\mu)$.  But $g$ is an odd function:  $$g(-x) = -x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-(-x)^2/(2\sigma^2)} = -x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} = -g(x).$$  Therefore, $g(-(x-\mu)) = -g(x-\mu)$; that is to say, if $g(x)$ is odd, $g(x-\mu)$ is **odd about $\mu$**.  This is simply another way of saying that the integrand is an odd function that has been location-shifted by $\mu$ units, thus its integral over the real line is zero.

Note we could not apply this "odd function" argument to the original integrand $x f_X(x)$, because it was not a location-shifted odd function; there is no constant $k$ such that $(x-k) f_X(x-k) = (x-k) f_X(-(x-k))$.  Had there been such a $k$, the integral would have been zero, but it is not:  it is $\mu$.